# What would be the algebraic generalization of the concept of “soundness” in mathematical logic?

Tags: abstract, mathematical-logic

Is there a corresponding/generalized concept of “soundness” as we abstract logical structures into algebraic ones? In the manner of algebraic logic: en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_logic

Let us say that proofs of soundness are simply proofs that the deduction rules of the logic are “truth-preserving”. I’m not sure, but the way I see it, formal logics are algebraic structured with *tons* of operators - a group is defined to have one binary operator, a ring two (with certain properties).. if a logic has a collection of n-ary operators (negation is unary, constants are nullary, conjunction is binary), we basic just have some algebraic structure, a set with k distinct operations, each of which is of arity n_(k_i).

But this is an algebra of functions with free variables - one analogous structure are polynomial rings. I think polynomial rings get generalized to algebraic varieties and then schemes, don’t they? So are we basically talking about algebraic geometry, here?

The question is, is there an analogous concept of “soundness”, in these generalized structures? I think more generally, it’s saying something like, each operation has a certain property… is it that they are identity-preserving?

I wonder if this could be expressed something like commutativity of operations? Like how diagrams commute in category theory?

I have a ton more thinking to do here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question here, and to move it to mathoverflow.net or math.stackexchange.com . This interesting question needs mathematical more than philosophical expertise.

Comment: @JoWehler might that not be too quick a judgment, here? There is an SEP entry on [algebraic propositional logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-algebraic-propositional/), after all, and I imagine Bumble, Conifold, and DoubleKnot, among others who contribute to this SE, would be able to provide useful comments/answers.

Comment: I would like to add that Mikhail Katz is a professor of mathematics at a major Israeli university, and he makes contributions here. David Gudeman is also well-versed in these kinds of topics, IIRC so is Annika, there's also user4894 (I think is the number for them), etc. ...

Comment: ^ although I am neither of these users, I will answer this in brief!

Comment: actually, here is an answer which already answers your question in depth: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2600683/link-between-boolean-algebras-and-propositional-logic?rq=1. See also section 5 of the SEP article mentioned above

Comment: Soundness is generally much easier than completeness for logical systems, if an algebra admits an interpretation of the syntax of your concerned logical system such as classic, intuitionistic or the famous justification logic (S4), then it must be sound insofar as such an algebra is non-empty and non-trivial...